# Can't override operator delete/new from pure abstract class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-management

I want to override new and delete operators of a class to make it use my memory pool.
It works with normal classes (no inheritance) but I fail to do that with classes which inherit from an abstract base class.

Name of the abstract base class: **MemTester**

Name of the concrete class which derives from MemTester: **BasicTester**

Here are the files (2 headers for each class and 2 CPP files for each class)

Here is the abstract base class:

```
class MemTester {
public:
    virtual void test() = 0;
    virtual ~MemTester() {}
    void* operator new(size_t sz);
    void * operator new[](size_t sz);
    void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept;
    void operator delete[](void* ptr) noexcept;
};
```

Here is the CPP file of the above header:

```
#include "..//headers//MemTester.h"
#include "..//headers//MemoryManager.h"

void * MemTester::operator new(size_t sz)
{
    return (void*)MemoryManager::allocate(sz);
}

void * MemTester::operator new[](size_t sz)
{
    return (void*)MemoryManager::allocateArr(sz);
}

void MemTester::operator delete(void * ptr) noexcept
{
    MemoryManager::free((char*)ptr);
}

void MemTester::operator delete[](void * ptr) noexcept
{
    MemoryManager::freeArr((char*)ptr);
}
```

And here is a header of a derived class which derived from the above base class:

```
#include "MemTester.h"
#include <cstddef>

class BasicTester : public MemTester {
public:
    void test();
    void* operator new(size_t sz);
    void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept;
private:
    void test1();
};
```

And it's CPP file:

```
#include "..//headers//BasicTester.h"
#include "..//headers//MemoryManager.h"
#include <iostream>

void BasicTester::test()
{
    test1();
}

void BasicTester::test1()
{
    std::cout << "====== Basic test 1 ======\n" << std::endl;
}

void * BasicTester::operator new(size_t sz)
{
    return (void*)MemoryManager::allocate(sz);
}

void BasicTester::operator delete(void * ptr) noexcept
{
    MemoryManager::free((char*)ptr);
}
```

## The problem:

When I call:

```
MemTester* mt = new BasicTester();
```

It calls why overriden `operator new` as expected.
But when I call

```
delete mt;
```

It calls the default `operator delete`

But if I write:
`MemTester::operator delete(mt);`
It calls the overriden op delete;

I don't understand why simply calling `delete p` when p is a pointer to a class without inheritance calling my op delete. But when I use a derived class I've to write `ClassName::operator delete (p)`

Comment: They are static member functions. You can't override them. And why are you bothering to re-define them just to do the exact same thing they are already defined to do in the base class?

Comment: I override them because I thought maybe it will work this way. How can I make it work like in a class without inheritance then? I've TestClass which is not deriving and when I call delete on a pointer of TestClass it calls the overriden `operator delete`. I want the same with inherited classes.

Comment: I never said it can't be made to work. Only corrected the terminology and questioned the need. And there's a few ways in which it may fail, but I can't easily test it since you don't provide a [mcve]. Either way, try adding `~BasicTester() = default;` at the end of the class definition of `BasicTester`. If it's the problem I think you have, it may very well fix it.

Comment: You need to make the base class's destructor virtual. This is the prime directive of polymorphic classes.

Answer (score 0):

Update: According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete :

> The deallocation function's name is looked up in the scope of the **dynamic** type of the object pointed to by expression, which means class-specific deallocation functions, if present, are found before the global ones. If :: is present in the delete expression, only the global namespace is examined by this lookup.

(emphasis mine)

This is wrong: The `operator delete` used is based on the type of the pointer that's being deleted, not on the type of the object the pointer points to.